# Landscape lighting (24V) flickering

Tags: electrical, lighting, landscaping

I have 5 24V DC landscape lights connected to a 150Wx2 transformer. All the lights were working fine and suddenly 3 of them (all connected to the same line on the transformer) started flickering.

Lights all work well, transformer appears to be outputting the right voltage, wiring ends before plugging the lights in yield proper voltage. But only one of the wires when I plug in a light it drops the voltage.

Here is what I have done to troubleshoot:

1. Disconnected all the lights and connected only 1 light that was flickering and it continued to flicker.
2. Redid all the connections.
3. Switched to the "non-flickering" output on the transformer.
4. Tested voltage: just before plugging in the flickering light, I measure 23.90V. When I add a low voltage extension and measure again, it stays at 23.90V. As soon as I plug in a any light, it drops to 16V.
5. On the side that does not flicker, connected to the same transformer, the same troubleshooting above yields 23.90V whether the lights are connected or not.

I'm completely out of ideas at this point. Any help would be great.

Comment: Wire insulation weak somewhere, when drawing amps(power/watts) get a minor short though insulation, no amps/power/watts, no leak.

Comment: Actually, much more likely is a bad connection causing a high resistance. As soon as you connect a light, the current draw causes the bad connection to drop voltage. Are you always measuring the voltage at the transformer? If so, the bad connection is probably inside the transformer and you’ll need to replace it.

Comment: I could also see a short circuit down the flickering line. Do you have a clamp ammeter? Can you clamp one of the power wires (hot or neutral) going into the transformer and see what current does? Or you can clamp one of the output wires if the transformer outputs AC.  If the 120VAC going into the transformer exceeds 2.5 amps, or if the 24VAC power out on one branch exceeds 7.5 amps, that indicates a short a good distance down the line.

Comment: Try reconnecting lights except the flickering one. Sometimes a LED light flickers, maybe it inspires the others to flicker?

Comment: Step 3: You have a flickering and a non-flickering output from the transformer? Why not just run all the lights from the non-flickering side if you don't want them to flicker, and why you expect anything _but_ flickering lights from the flickering output?

Comment: @FreeMan Both outputs will flicker as long as I connect the lights through the same wire. I'm suspecting as someone suggests above that the wire has somehow poor insulation somewhere (under the concrete slab probably). I'll probably need to retire that entire wire and start new.